# What is the difference between a D-Bus signal and a D-Bus property

Tags: dbus

Basic difference between D-Bus signal & D-Bus property.
Are this two same.
When we have to use D-Bus signal & D-Bus property?

Answer (score 5):

DBus property represent a state and you need to ask for its value. DBus Signal are like 'events', you can register to them and you will receive changes notifications on your Signal Handlers. See the specification for more info: http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html

Comment: Indeed, the concepts are the same as in many object oriented programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

Use DBus signals, if you have to notify an application about an event that has occured.

Use DBus properties, if you want to have the application get the value of a property at any time. Additionally, you can have a property-changed-handler, to notify you about value changes of a specific property.